# OrmLite one to many in C# .Net

Tags: c#, database, firebird, ormlite-servicestack

I have two classes

```
public class A
{
public A()
{
_b = new List<B>();
}

public int id {get;set;}
public List<B> _b {get;set;}
}

public class B
{
 public int Id {get;set;}
 public string Caption {get;set;}
}
```

And i have to tables in db with the same structure as classes.

When i try to populate class A data from Db i have error "Column unknown" for field _b.
How can i properly map fields from DB to classes in one to many case?
Database server is firebird 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OrmLite does not provide automatic loading of related entities. You will have to fire off another query to get List.

Your class A should not contain `List<B>`

Your class B should contain field

```
public int AId { get; set; }
```

You can decorate it with ForeignKey  and other related attributes to get cascading deletion.

Comment: Could you provide some example in my case?

Comment: This page contains all the information needed to do it: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite